# Can we use tf-idf and cosine similarity for document recommendation system?

Tags: python, nlp, recommendation-engine, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

The document dataset is having 9000 documents and its growing day by day, most of the documents having average 1-3 paragraphs.

The idea is to make a recommendation with the help of user's past usage of documents.

Lets say the dataset is having 10 documents (main corpus) in total and out of them 4 related to sports, 2 related to Fashion, 4 related to technology.

Now if say user x has read 2 sports and 1 technology related documents then to get the tf-idf of the user x we will combine these 3 documents and assume it as user x corpus.

Now get the tf-idf of the 10 documents (main corpus) which will get us the individual tf idf vector of all those 10 documents.

Now compare the cosine similarity of user x corpus with the main corpus (10 document)

Result should be 2 sports document and 1 technology document which user x has not yet read.

Let me know if this idea makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense to me. But i guess in reality you have larger vocabulary than 3 topics. Right?

Comment: In a word: no. Why? The curse of dimensionality. I.e., Your vocabulary size (dimensions) will by far out-weigh any other factor in your approach, and so most words will have been unseen (i.e., zero TF-IDF) with respect to the user's set of documents.

Comment: @fnl what could be the best way to do it ?

Comment: That will get quite complicated and is very tricky, I fear: A very careful selection strategy for the features of your classifier, a simple, robust classifier that works well on tiny datasets, and, ideally, including some nifty way of adding a deep representation learner to the setup...